# Keeping matplotlib images in-memory until it is ready to be plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, in-memory

I have a situation where in a loop, I perform some calculations, then plot the results and assign a score to each of the plots. At the end, I sort the plots by their scores in descending order. Maybe the top quarter is needed and the rest discarded. I then generate a html file with the saved images.

The plotting and saving slows down the process. Is there some way of storing matplotlib images in memory?

For the MCVE, consider the following code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

score_list = []
for a in range(50):
    score = random.random()
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
    ax.plot([0, 0], [1, 1], 'r--')
    fig.savefig('{}.png'.format(a))
    plt.close(fig)
    score_list.append(['{}.png'.format(a), score])

sorted_score_list = sorted(score_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(sorted_score_list)
```

The MCVE might have over-simplified the issue. The scoring actually dictates what gets plotted. Carrying that information around and delaying the plotting is not undoable but I am wondering if there's some other solution where I can keep a certain number of images in-memory.

Comment: Why not append your figures in a list?

Comment: You mean score_list.append([fig, score])? Sometimes matplotlib writes to the same figure. Do I need to plt.close(fig) in the loop as well?

Comment: It should not if you are creating a new figure each time. You could even not store them in a list, and just access them later with [`get_fignums`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=gcf#matplotlib.pyplot.get_fignums)

Comment: Do you mind writing up an answer so that I can test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably achieve what you want by affecting an specific index to your figure and then getting them later using the same index :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

score_list = []
for a in range(50):
    score = random.random()
    fig = plt.figure(a)
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
    ax.plot([0, 0], [1, 1], 'r--')
    score_list.append(['{}'.format(a), score])

sorted_score_list = sorted(score_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Saving the first 10 ones by score
for idx, score in sorted_score_list[:10]:
    fig = plt.figure(idx)
    fig.savefig('{}.png'.format(idx))
    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Does it work if I have several for loops in front, say a, b, c? Can I assign it this way:fig = plt.figure((a,b,c))?

Comment: No, but you could use a simple encoding to calculate your indexes. (like `100*a+10*b+c` if your loops are not bigger than 10), or use a string "abc" (that is going to be the title of your plot though). 
But keep in mind that this is very memory inefficient. You are better delaying the plotting IHMO.

Comment: Right now, my solution is put a cutoff on the scores and not plot it at all if it's below the cutoff. That seems to cut down the number of plots by 80%.  Thanks for your answer.